# In Classic ASP "On Button Click " Data in the text boxes need to post to the Stored Procedure Parameters

Tags: asp-classic

I designed an classic ASP application. In that i need to search the Employee Details by clicking Search Button. But it was not happening.

My ASP Page Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nothwind Employees Details</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">

    <form method="POST" action="EmpDetailsbySrch.asp">
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Emp ID:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtId" size="10" />
            </td>
            <td>
                First Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" size="10" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Last Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtLastName" size="10" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Employee Role:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtTitle" size="10" />
            </td>
            <td>
                City:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtCity" size="10" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick=""/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <% 
Dim adoCon
Dim rsEmployees
Dim strSQL

EmpId =  request.Form("txtId")
LastName =  request.Form("txtLastName")
FirstName =  request.Form("txtFirstName")
Role =  request.Form("txtTitle")
City =  request.Form("txtCity")

Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
StrCnn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=Wissen@01;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=NORTHWND;Data Source=WISBLR2410"
adoCon.Open StrCnn


strSQL = "EXECUTE [dbo].[USP_EmpDetbySrch]"


set rsEmployees = adoCon.Execute(strSQL)


Response.write "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' align='Center'>"
Response.write "<tr>"
dim field
For Each field in rsEmployees.Fields
Response.write "<th>" & field.Name & "</th>"
Next
Response.write "</tr>"

dim x : x = 0
Do While Not rsEmployees.EOF
Response.write "<tr>"
For Each field in rsEmployees.Fields
Response.write "<td>" & rsEmployees(field.Name) & "</td>"
Next
Response.write "</tr>"
x = x + 1
rsEmployees.MoveNext
Loop

Response.write "</table>"

adoCon.Close
Set adoCon = Nothing
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Stored Procedure with Parameters:

```
USE [NORTHWND]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_EmpDetbySrch]    Script Date: 5/27/2016 2:35:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      SR
-- Create date: <25-May-2016>
-- Description: Get Employee Details of NORTHWIND DB
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_EmpDetbySrch] 
@EmpId int = NULL,
@FirstName nvarchar(20) = NULL,
@LastName nvarchar(10) = NULL,
@Role nvarchar(30) = NULL,
@City nvarchar(15) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT [EmployeeID]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[Title]
      ,[TitleOfCourtesy]
      ,[BirthDate]
      ,[HireDate]
      ,[Address]
      ,[City]
      ,[Region]
      ,[PostalCode]
      ,[Country]
      ,[HomePhone]
      ,[Extension]
  FROM [dbo].[Employees]
  WHERE [EmployeeID] = ISNULL(@EmpId,EmployeeID) OR [LastName] = ISNULL(@LastName,LastName) OR [FirstName] = ISNULL(@FirstName,FirstName)
  OR [Title] = ISNULL(@Role,Title) OR [City] = ISNULL(@City,City)

END
```

I designed an classic ASP application. In that i need to search the Employee Details by clicking Search Button. But it was not happening. Please Suggest how to do this and where i went wrong.

Comment: it seems no where you pass the parameters into the store procedure in asp. please check.

Comment: Thank You.. Daniel. I missed to pass the parameters